# Swift - Remove default "Go-to-top-on-active"-function from UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

By default a UISearchController moves to the top of the screen, when you click on the textfield. Is there a way to prevent this action from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to prevent this behavior by setting a certain property on the `UISearchController`:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

More detail on this property is available in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618650-hidesnavigationbarduringpresenta?language=swift)

Comment: I have this in my ViewDidLoad? But it dont seems to work - Is that the right place to put it?

Comment: @LasseBickmann You can try putting it in `viewDidAppear`, but I doubt that will make a difference. Are you re-instantiating a new `UISearchController` at any other point?